# How to get the title of a window opened by a popup?

Tags: javascript, popup

I am opening a popup of another site (google oauth2). The site I load will display information in the title bar, so I want to monitor the title bar to extract the information. Whenever I do this, however, the title is always blank even though the window does have a title. Here is what I am trying right now just for testing.

```
var authWindow = null;

function popup(url) {
    authWindow = window.open(url, 'Authentication', 'height=600,width=450');

    if (window.focus) {
        authWindow.focus();
    }

    $(authWindow.document).ready(monitorForAuthCode);
}

function monitorForAuthCode()
{
    if (authWindow && authWindow.closed == false)
    {
        var code = authWindow.document.title;

        $('#hash').html($('#hash').html() + code + '<br>');

        setTimeout(monitorForAuthCode, 1000);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> popup of another site (google oauth2)

You can not read the contents of another domain because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Then somebody needs to tell Google they are wrong, or I am misunderstanding what they are stating. From their OAuth2 guide at http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html for native applications they state: On many platforms, your application should be able to monitor the window title of a browser window it creates and close the window when it sees a valid response. If your platform doesn't support that, you can instruct users to copy and paste the code to your application.

Comment: @esac The trick is that this is intended for _native applications_, where not all of the app is subject to JavaScript's cross-origin restrictions. For example, the native-code part of your app could use native APIs to examine the titlebar. Or, if your app is using an embedded browser instance like [CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/), you could configure it to disable cross-origin restrictions (make sure you only ever load your own trusted JS code into the browser pane, though).